# Is there a way to resize the text to fit a UITextView using Swift? I've seen a few examples from years ago but they're written in Objective-C

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uitextview

I have a view with a set width and height and I want the text to resize, not the view. One example of what I'm trying to achieve is the instagram 'Yes/No' poll. The text shrinks to fit inside the view without resizing it. [image: This is an example of what I'm trying to do:]

Comment: So what’s the question exactly?

Comment: How would I resize the text in real time to fit the view? I'm not trying to resize the view to fit the text. Please tell me if my question needs more clarity

Comment: It needs more clarity. I understand what you want to do, but then why do you not do it? I mean, this is not going to happen by magic. Changing the text size is going to be up to you. What’s the hard part exactly? Is it that you don’t know what size to resize it to? Or do you not know how to resize it at all? Or what?

Comment: I can't figure out how to resize the text while typing in the textView at the same time. There's no 'adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth' for UITextView. I know what size I want to resize it to but I don't know how to resize it at all.

Comment: Okay so a text view has an attributed text that includes a font size. So you detect the user typing and change the size as needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of a UITextView, if you use a UILabel or UITextField, you can set .        textField.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = TRUE. Alternatively, with a UILabel, you can set the minimumFontSize (you can also set the label.numberOfLines if you want need more than 1 line). There are alternatives that work with UITextView, but I don't believe they're as simple.

Comment: I chose to use UITextView because it can have multiple lines unlike UITextField